# scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline how to retrieve all the coefficients?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, coefficients, cubic-spline

I have the following program:

```
nknots = 4
x_i = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_i = [1, np.exp(1), np.exp(2), np.exp(3)]
coeff = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x_i, y_i, bc_type="natural")
```

I want to construct a cubic spline using the knots whose coordinates are given by x_i and y_i arrays. However, I'm having a hard time obtaining all the coefficients. A cubic spline function has the following form:

```
y_i(x) = a + b*(x - x_i) + c*(x - x_i)^2 + d*(x - x_i)^3
```

When I do

```
print(coeff(x_i))
```

I get only the array of *a* values:

```
[ 1.          2.71828183  7.3890561  20.08553692]
```

However, I'm missing the arrays for the *b*, *c*, and *d* coefficients. How do I extract those? Or are there steps I'm missing? I read the scipy documentation on make_interp_spline but I didn't understand how to get the *b*, *c* and *d* coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [`interpolate.CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html).  It's much more convenient if what you're after are the polynomial coefficients.  Using your variables:

```
spl = interpolate.CubicSpline( x_i, y_i )
spl.c

array([[-1.57973952e-01,  2.93118310e-01, -1.35144359e-01],
       [ 1.11022302e-16, -4.73921855e-01,  4.05433076e-01],
       [-3.01723742e-01, -7.75645598e-01, -8.44134377e-01],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  5.40302306e-01, -4.16146837e-01]])
```

see the [`PPoly`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.html#scipy.interpolate.PPoly) doc for how the piecewise polynomial coefficients are stored.

Addendum:
It's *possible* to extract the coefficients from the output of `make_interp_spline`, but  <strike>it's not straightforward</strike> it requires an extra step described by @ev-br because "coefficients" for **B**Splines (emphasis on the B) are not the same as the polynomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Given `spl = make_interp_spline(...)`, the `spl` is a BSpline object which has `spl.t` as the knots and `spl.c` the coefficients --- in the b-spline basis. If you really need the coefficients in the power basis, you can evaluate the derivatives of use `PPoly.from_spline(spl)`.

Or indeed use `СubicSpline` which works in the power basis. (See the answer by @bogovicj)