# Actually retrieving the polynomial from Multivariate Polynomial Regression using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The project I am working on is almost identical to the problem outlined at this link:

https://financetrain.com/multivariate-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-library

As a summary, there are N independent x variables, and one dependent y variable. I have followed the steps on that website and replicated results on my own data.

However, I would like to get a polynomial (of any degree) to model the regression performed. Can someone point me in the right direction to doing this?

I can give more details if needed, but I have no experience statistics, so if there is a better way to go about this, recommendations are very very welcome!

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679091/scipy-interpolate-make-interp-spline-how-to-retrieve-all-the-coefficients/63679858#63679858

Comment: @bogovicj From what I understand, that is only used for relating ONE set of x values to one set of y values. My data has multiple sets of x values

Comment: it really depends on how you want to model each term? I mean if you have 5 x independent variables, you want to do a polynomial on each them?

Comment: can you elaborate more, right now it's a bit unclear

Comment: @StupidWolf My goal is a polynomial that combines the 5 x independent variables in any way to model the relationship between x and y. So, with future x values, I can plug them into this polynomial and estimate future y values. Please let me know if you want more elaboration.